# Pass a method as a prop to the class static function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can't solve this issue by myself. I have a Class

```
class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url: 'https://example.org',
    };
  }
  
  someMethod = () => {
    return 'something';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: this.state.url}}
        />
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: () => (
        <AddressBar navigation={navigation} />
      ),
    };
  };
}
```

I want to access `someMethod` from `static navigationOptions`

---

#### I've tried the following without the success:

run `this.someMethod()`

run `WebViewScreen.someMethod()`

`let _this` outside a class, then `_this = this` from a WebViewScreen Class constructor
then `_this.someMethod()` from `static navigationOptions`

---

My question is, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What about making your `someMethod` static too?

Comment: What exactly does `someMethod` return? If it's the same for every component based on the class, simply make `someMethod` static, too. If it's based on, say, the component's individual state, one way is to pass the instance (`this`) as parameter to the static function so it has access to the instance (and therefore the instance methods). Given the answers you got this seems to be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the component's state from within a static method. What you can do is keeping a navigation's parameter in sync with your local state and/or pass functions to it with

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  someMethod: this.someMethod.bind(this)
})
```

which you can retrieve with:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const someMethod = navigation.getParam('someMethod', () => null)
  // ... someMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a build-in function in React Navigation 4 called: [setParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#setparams-make-changes-to-route-params). This function could be used to set params in static navigationOptions, however in React Navigation 5 there will be a dynamic way to change the navigation. Until then you should use `setParams`. In your WebViewScreen component you should use it like this.

```
class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url: 'https://example.org'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.setParams({ logOut: this.someMethod });
  }

  someMethod = () => {
    return 'log out';
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <WebView source={{ uri: this.state.url }} />
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  static navigationOptions = ({
    navigation,
    navigation: {
      state: { params }
    }
  }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: () => <AddressBar navigation={navigation} />,
      headerRight: (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.someMethod()}>
          Log out
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    };
  };
}
```

Important to note: you can only add params to the static nav, when the component is mounted!